# mkdir() File exists

Tags: php, mkdir

I am trying to create a new directory in the images folder when the email and password is sent, it retrieves the ID of the user and creates a folder in the images folder according to the users ID, however it is not working as I get this error:

```
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in C:\Users\authenticate.php on line 101
```

This is what I have tried and this is what it is giving a warning on:

```
  // Otherwise, the result variable passes on the confirm-email and the confirm-password to the login function
               $result = $userVeri->login(strtolower($_POST["confirm-email"]), $_POST["confirm-password"]);
               // The row variable stores the result
               $row = $result;
               // Then make a directory in the images folder with the new user id and give the folder all priveleges
               mkdir('images/'.$row["id"],0777);
               exit;
               // Then display this message
               echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Congratulations! your account has been created. Please sign in.</div>';
```

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

BTW it gives this warning even when their is no folder that exists in the images folder

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($result)`, to see if `$result['id']` exists? If it doesn't, then you're effectively doing `mkdir('images/')` and (hopefully) that directory already exists, so the error is 100% accurate.

Comment: I've no idea what does your login method and what it returns, but it looks like `row["id"]` is an empty string and so mkdir try to create the images/ directory and it already exist. add a test like (pseudo code) `if (strlen($row["id"]) > 0) mkdir ... else echo "No id found"`

Comment: where is `$row["id"]` defined ?

Comment: @MarcB I have put exit; after mkdir however, the echo is still displaying even after it has been exited before it reaches it?

Comment: @Tensibai I have done that, it does not echo anything and still does not create the folder

Comment: Maybe it's because your login method does not return an array with a key named id ... + the exit after mkdir stop the interpreter to do anything else so your echo will never be printed.

Comment: @Tensibai Right, i've found out the problem, for some strange reason it is saving the folder elsewhere. Like it is not saving it in my parent Directory which is Documents/SSP/Project.. it is saving it here Users/PHPstormProject/Project which is strange, do you have any idea why it is doing this?

Comment: Yes, you're calling mkdir with a relative path, which is relative to the caller process working directory and not to your script file. use full path, with the help of `dirname($_PHP['SELF'])` (from meeory so check the variable name)

Comment: @Tensibai Okay thanks, could you help implement what you have just said into mine and post is an answer please?

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP's `is_dir($path_to_dir)` for checking if a directory exists from before. Or you can use this code

```
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0700);
}
```

Comment: There's a race condition here, as the directory might be created between the call to `file_exists()` and `mkdir()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Otherwise, the result variable passes on the confirm-email and the confirm-password to the login function
$result = $userVeri->login(strtolower($_POST["confirm-email"]), $_POST["confirm-password"]);
// The row variable stores the result
$row = $result;
// Then make a directory in the images folder with the new user id and give the folder all priveleges
mkdir(__DIR__.'/images/'.$row["id"],0777);
// Then display this message
echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Congratulations! your account has been created. Please sign in.</div>';
```

I've added no check on the success or not of mkdir nor on the value returned by the login method. 
Rechecked the manual for my memory idea and found the prefered method is now with magic constant `__DIR__` instead (which contains the path to the script file)

Answer (score 0):

The errors `Warning: mkdir(): File exists` and `Warning: rmdir(): File exists` are telling that the folder is not empty. PHP can only delete folders that are empty, and mkdir can only create a directory if it doesn't exist. They emit a warning as they are not working recursively.
In Linux, there is another quirk, as empty directories are seen as files, making `is_dir()` behavior confusing.

The folder files content must be deleted first.

```
// A directory somedir exist and contain files, this delete them all
$files = glob("somedir/*");
foreach($files as $file){
    unlink($file);
}
// The folder is now empty, but is seen as a regular file by the OS
if (is_file("somedir")){
  rmdir("somedir"); // No warning, directory deleted
}
mkdir("somedir");   // No warning, new directory created
```